# Mapboxgl performance drops when adding lots of html markers

Tags: mapbox-gl

I'm adding 300+ html markers with a background image (1kb) to my map. But when zooming the performance drops significally compared to for example 50 markers. Is there a way to increase performance?

```
for(var ii = 0; ii < length; ii++) {

  // Create html element for marker
  var element: any = document.createElement('div');
  element.className += (' marker-' + status + '-' + type);
  self.markers.push(
    new mapboxgl.Marker(element, {
      offset: {
        x: -20, /* Half width marker css */
        y: -40 /* Height markers css */
      }
    })
    .setLngLat([store.lng, store.lat])
    .addTo(self.map)
  );

}
```

It's not the adding which is slow but the rendering of the markers when zooming or changing the map.

Comment: Would clustering the markers be a suitable solution? https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/cluster/

Comment: Thought of it, but how can I open a custom html + databinding with clusters..  For each point I want to open a specific popup like for example:
<div><img [src]="obj.photo" /></div>

Comment: With Supercluster you can easily retrieve any cluster children or leaves https://github.com/mapbox/supercluster